# Maya and a Database

Tags: mysql, excel, animation, maya, vba

I had a project last year where I was given a database of user information.

For each of these entries, I created an animation for each. Their name fading in and fading out. Fairly simple. But this was monotonous as I had to load a file each time, change the text and re-render to an output.

Is there a way I can use a mysql/excel database to do this process as a batch script?

So I can record a macro, load a script linking the database and press go - creating the animation for each of the entries, saving me loads of time.

Is there a solution for this in Maya, After effects?

Comment: Sure you can do this in both Maya and after effects no problem whatsoever. But would be best if you showed us what you have tried so far so we know where to start. Anyway as the question is posed currently its a bit too much asked, because we wouldn't know where to begin when we dont know anything about your scenes or so. Anyway both applications are built on nodes so you dont need to record stuff just change the text string in one node or so. So which is it after effects or maya?

Comment: Hi I made one in AE last year, it was a very simple animation. Text was faded in from opacity(0) to opacity(1). I had to render over 400 animations, changing the text each time. This is why the question is so simple. It's a simple question, if you get what I mean. When you asked maya or after effects. This year, for the project i'm making the animations in maya, and I wondered if mysql or an excel document would be the best to be the database that holds the different text values. Thanks for responding anyway! reputation++ :)

Comment: okay ill device an answer but understand that you have two or three separate questions here.

Comment: The main question is to use some script that loops, creating the outputs without having to render them all individually. Does that sound better?

Comment: not really, the runtime environment you use, what if any render management software you use, what kinds of assets ypu render into, what operating system you use, what devenv and language you prefer and wether you use maya or AE.

Comment: right, well i'll cut it down for you. So i'm using windows 8.1. After effects CC, or any earlier versions. I render into a simple mp4. I prefer to use php, but willing to try any other dev lang. If you think its best to do this in Maya. Let me know as i'm willing to do it in either. Basically whatever is easier is better.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Im working on a solution in the amswer you havevsuggested if you could bear with me.

Comment: No problem take your time ask if you need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Introduction

There are several questions here, and the question can not really be answered very well without having access to your computer setup and scenes. I can easily think of 20 different variations for AE and 50 for Maya. But all in all there's probably more than a hundred of ways.

#### Database

Because the path form your database can be varied and your may need to be able to switch databases. So just export your table as a bunch of names per line, tab delimited or comma delimited file. This eliminates the need to go into specifics of your database handling. Now your fronted could just as easily be excel or even oracles database.

#### After Effects

Looping over the database entries can be done in quite many ways. Adobe ships with 2-4 different API's to accomplish this. What you use depends on what you want the result to be, one continuous sequence, individual frames or individual animation files (*I strongly suggest making renders separately and then compression separately* for production related reasons).

Easiest is to use a extend toolkit script file to drive your AE, the scripting manuals can be found [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/aftereffects.html), and [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/scripts.html). First lets assume your project has:

1. One comp named "Comp 1"

   1. Comp has one Text layer "Text 1"

You can now accesses and change the text layer in extend script as follows:

```js
var firstComp = app.project.item(1);
var textLayer = firstComp.layers[1];
textLayer.property("Source Text").setValue("John Doe");
```

What you want to do is iterate over the names and change the text and render

```js
var dataPath = "D:\\temp\\test.txt";
var outPath = "/d/temp/";
var firstComp = app.project.item(1);
var textLayer = firstComp.layers[1];


var fileObject = File ( dataPath ) ;
fileObject.open ('r');

while ( ! fileObject.eof ) {
    var name = fileObject.readln() ;
    textLayer.property("Source Text").setValue(name);
    name = name.replace(" ","_");
    renderJob = app.project.renderQueue.items.add(firstComp); 
    OM = renderJob.outputModule(1);
    OM.file= new File(outPath+name+".avi");
    app.project.renderQueue.render();
}
```

That's it if you run this and your scene entries relative positions are as described then it would just loop over each name in the file and be done with this.

#### Maya

In Maya i would use a slightly different strategy, instead of populating and calling render inside Maya i would modify the scene on the render call from command line. This is both safer and better. While the command line in windows is relatively feature poor it works quite fine here.

So assuming your text is made with bevel node *bevel1* calling following rather long command line would swap the name of output file and the text and render output:

```
render -preRender "setAttr ""defaultRenderGlobals.imageFilePrefix"" -type ""string"" ""foos""; setAttr -type ""string"" textForBevel1.text ""foos""; " test.ma
```

Now its a matter of wrapping this up in a batch for loop

```bat
echo off
set code="setAttr ""defaultRenderGlobals.imageFilePrefix"" -type ""string"" ""%%G""; setAttr -type ""string"" textForBevel1.text ""%%G"";" 

for /f "tokens=*" %%G IN (test.txt) DO ( 
    render -preRender %code% test.ma
)
```

Why batch? well it's simple but there's another reason would Maya exit with errors on one of the lines it would continue on the rest. And wrapping this into any of your render managers would be trivial.

Other methods are available

Comment: Hi again. Regarding what you have shown using ae. Well it works perfectly. This will work despite adding animation to the text layer right? I'm yet to test it on maya so i'll report back with another comment when I do! :) cheers